# Populating the Zone field in function of telephone prefix

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to populate a field in function of data stored in another field? I explain me better: in a database there is a field "telnum" (telephone number) where are stored telepnone numbers with international prefix. Can i populate the "country" field in function of the prefix of each number using a php command?

This is the database:

```
  ______________________________________________
  |  id  |   telnum   |   name   |   country   |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |  01  | 003912377  |   Smith  |             |
  |  02  | 004412345  |   White  |             |
  |  03  | 005454321  |   Lopez  |             |
```

The "php command" should associate to each different prefix the country name in my sql table. In the example we have 0039 -> Italy, 0044 -> UK, 0054 -> Argentina... and so on.
Result must be this:

```
  ______________________________________________
  |  id  |   telnum   |   name   |   country   |
  ----------------------------------------------
  |  01  | 003912377  |   Smith  |   Italy     |
  |  02  | 004412345  |   White  |    UK       |
  |  03  | 005454321  |   Lopez  |  Argentina  |
```

Thanks in advance to everybody for your help.
Greetings, Mattew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` statement within a query

```
update table
set country =
case 
when left(telnum,4) = 0039 then 'Italy'
when left(telnum,4) = 0044 then 'UK'
when left(telnum,4) = 0054 then 'Argentina'
else ''
end
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I found very easy and useful the code of your answer and it works perfectly. Could I use the same script to populate also more fields? For example I'd like to add in the field continent "eu" when prefix is of Italy, "america" for argentina... and so on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

YES,

If you already have a country code mapping
(that's mean another table with country_code + country_name),
you can perform a INNER JOIN like :-

```
 select u.id, u.telnum, u.name, c.country_name
 from user as u
 inner join country c
 on left(u.telnum, 4) = c.country_code
 ...;
```

Otherwise, you could put the mapping into a PHP configuration file,
with format like

```
$country_code = array();
$country_code['0039'] = ...;
```

Then when you iterate the result from mysql,
you can do mapping accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**mySQL query way:**

```
UPDATE telcountry_table
SET country =
CASE 
   WHEN left(telnum,4) = 0093 THEN 'Afghanistan'
   WHEN left(telnum,5) = 00355 THEN 'Albania'
   WHEN left(telnum,5) = 00213 THEN 'Algeria'
   .
   .
   .
   ELSE ''
END
```

Full version of query: https://gist.github.com/1395484#file_mysql_phoneprefix_to_zone_field.sql

**php way:**

```
$call_code = array();
$call_code['93']='Afghanistan';
$call_code['355']='Albania';
$call_code['213']='Algeria';
.
.
.

$func = function($value) {
   $code2=substr($value['telnum'],2,2);
   $code3=substr($value['telnum'],2,3);
   $code4=substr($value['telnum'],2,4);
   if(array_key_exists($code2,$call_code))
      $value['country']=$call_code[$code2];
   else if(array_key_exists($code3,$call_code))
      $value['country']=$call_code[$code3];
   else if(array_key_exists($code4,$call_code))
      $value['country']=$call_code[$code4];
   return $value;
};

$countries=array_map($func,$data);
```

Full version of script: https://gist.github.com/1395484#file_php_phoneprefix_to_zone_field.php

Comment: Thank you so much! As I said to the other friend, I found very easy and useful the code of your answer and it works perfectly (I refer to the "MySQL query way" of your nswer). Could I use the same script structure to populate also more fields? For example I'd like to add in the field continent "eu" when prefix is of Italy, "america" for argentina... and so on. Otherwise how i need to modify the global script (MyQSL way)?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just set another column in the same way:
after `country=CASE ... END` add `, continent=CASE **replace country names with continent code** END`